# How do I connect a device from AWS Device Farm to my local network?

Tags: manual-testing

I am trying to manually test a web app. We're using AWS servers. Security is set so that I must be on the company's local network or VPN. I am exploring Device Farm for testing mobile devices. I launched a remote Galaxy S5 (Verizon) device and tried accessing the site using Chrome. It didn't work and I wasn't able to quickly figure out how to connect to my local network.

Comment: Any updates regarding this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: I wasn't able to figure it out.